# ProgressBar to increase by the value in a NumericUpDown box

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, numericupdown

I am coding a form in C# in which you enter a value in a NumericUpDown box and when the button is clicked underneath the progress bar will increase by the value entered.

I used a timer for this with the code being :

```
 private void ProgressBar_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (filesize <= 60)
            sixtyfree.Increment(filesize);

    }
```

filesize is the name of the NumericUpDown box, i have converted this value to an int so that it would work with this. The problem i face is that no matter what number under 60 i enter it fills the progress bar all the way, instead of only by the amount that is entered in "filesize", can anyone help me solve this ?

Yeah ofcourse, here is my full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Worst_fit_algorithm_GUI
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    int filesize;
    int progressBarSetValue = 40; //The set value of first progressBar
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void downloadfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ProgressBar.Start();


    }

    private void ProgressBar_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sixtyfree.Value <= sixtyfree.Maximum - progressBarSetValue)
        {
            sixtyfree.Value = progressBarSetValue + (int)filesize;
            ProgressBar.Stop();
        }


    }

    private void FileSize_ValueChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        filesize = Convert.ToInt32(FileSize.Value);

    }

    private void sixtyfree_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the max value of the progressbar ? Definitely something around 60 right ?

Comment: It has a set value of 40 already and the max value is 100, i want the inputted number to add on to this 40

Comment: sixtyfree looks like the NumericUpDown control.  If filesize never changes, then the progress bar will always increment until it reaches the maximum.  I *think* you want something like `if (sixtyfree.Value + filesize <= 60)`

Comment: If you are going to increment based on a filesize, then what value you think is appropriate for the maximum of the progressbar. It does not make any sense to use it that way. A proper use would be to set the maximum of the progressbar to the filesize and to set the value of the progressbar to the number of bytes you have read from the file. And to do that till you read everything.

Comment: Ok so i added:
 if (sixtyfree.Value <= filesize)
                (sixtyfree.Value + filesize);
Hoping that if the value of filesize is equal to or less than the value of sixtyfree then it will be added on however i keep getting the error:
Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `ValueChanged` event to set the progressbar. You can use a timer as you have done:

```
int progressBarSetValue = 40; //The set value of progressBar you want

private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (numericUpDown1.Value <= progressBar1.Maximum - progressBarSetValue)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = progressBarSetValue + (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
    }
}
```

The code is more generic, meaning you don't have to use a fixed `60` value. You can change the progressbar maximum without caring if the numericupdown value will overflow the progressbar, as long as the `progressBarSetValue` is not larger than the `progressBar1.Maximum`.

**EDIT**

*numericUpDown control name = FileSize, progressBar control name = sixtyfree*

```
private void ProgressBar_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (filesize <= sixtyfree.Maximum - sixtyfree.Value)
    {
        sixtyfree.Value += filesize;
    }
    else
    {
        sixtyfree.Value = sixtyfree.Maximum;
    }

    ProgressBar.Stop();
}
```

Comment: I have added this and it works a charm, however there are 60 free slots and lets say i add 40 the progress bar will increase but then if i add another value after, lets say 20 it should complete the progress bar, but after i have pressed the button once nothing happens again no matter the value i type in.

Comment: @user3596350 What is the button you are reffering to? Where do you add the 40 and 20 values? Can you show your code?

Comment: Okay i have added my full code to my original, sorry i wasnt meant to edit yours and add it to that.
Basically there is a button located under the NumericUpDown Box so that when pressed the number that the user has entered will be added to the progress bar until reaching its maximum

Answer (score -1):

Use 
ProgressBar.Value = filesize ;